# E(X), V(X), P(X$\ge$ 4) for colored candies in Jar

Tags: probability, expectation, sampling

A jar contains 3 red candies, 3 yellow candies, 3 green, 3 blue, and 3 orange. Amy, John, and Sandy take candies from the jar one after the other. First, Amy takes 3 candies. Then John takes 5 candies, and then Sandy takes 7 candies. A color is said to be "loved" if all candies of that color are eaten by the same person. Let X denote the number of loved candies.
a) Find E(X)
b) find V(X)
c) Find P(X$\ge$4)

Not really sure how to proceed. Would it make sense to take a combinatoric approach and say, "there's 15 candies,  I can arrange them all in a line in 15! ways"? Or would it be better to just compute the individual probabilities, such as the probability Amy takes 1/2/3 colors, John takes 2/3/4/5 colors, and Sandy takes....well I'm already confused so I guess that's not a good approach.

Comment: Linearity of expectation should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Use numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ instead of colors and let $B_i$ denote a random variable that takes value $1$ if candy $i$ is loved and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^5B_i$ .

Now apply linearity of expectation and symmetry to find $\mathbb EX$.

Further exploit: $$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5\mathsf{Cov}(B_i,B_j)=20\mathsf{Cov}(B_1,B_2)+5\mathsf{Var}(B_1)$$

For finding $P(X\geq4)$ you can start with the observation that $X\geq4$ implies that Amy took $3$ candies of the same color.

Comment: I still need to find the probability that color i is chosen, don't I? And I'm not sure how to do that. This seems like a hypergeometric distribution, except the population size and number of successes changes for  John, and Sandy depending on the previous results.   Or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: Yes, you must find the probability that color i is loved (it equals the expectation of $B_i=B_i^2$). You can find it as P(Amy ate all of i)+P(John ate all of i)+P(Sandy ate all of i). The addition of probabilities of mutually exclusive events.